# SWF: How can I signal the parent workflow from the child workflow?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I'm trying to signal my parent workflow to update its state variable. The parent workflow id is passed to the child workflow's `execute` method.

```
@Autowired
private AmazonSimpleWorkflowClient swfClient;
@Autowired
private String swfDomain;

private ParentWorkflowClientExternalFactory clientExternalFactory = new ParentWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl(swfClient, swfDomain);

@Override
public Promise<String> childActivityMethod(String parentWorkflowId) {
    ParentWorkflowClientExternal clientExternal = clientExternalFactory.getClient(parentWorkflowId);
    clientExternal.updateState(...);
}
```

However, this throws a `NullPointerException` in SWF code (AmazonSimpleWorkflow is null):

```
["java.lang.NullPointerException",{"cause":null,"stackTrace":[{"methodName":"signalWorkflowExecution","fileName":"GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl.java","lineNumber":87,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.GenericWorkflowClientExternalImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"signalWorkflowExecution","fileName":"DynamicWorkflowClientExternalImpl.java","lineNumber":167,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.DynamicWorkflowClientExternalImpl","nativeMethod":false},...
```

When I initialize the `ClientExternalFactory` without the parameters:

```
private ParentWorkflowClientExternalFactory clientExternalFactory = new ParentWorkflowClientExternalFactoryImpl();
```

The exception thrown is: `The required property genericClient is null. It could be caused by instantiating the factory through the default constructor instead of the one that takes service and domain arguments.`

`ParentWorkflow#updateState` does this:

```
private MyWorkflowState state;

// This method has @Signal in the interface.
@Override
public void updateState(MyWorkflowState newState) {
    state = newState;
}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of clients generated from the workflow interfaces. The internal and external ones. Internal are expected to be used from within a workflow code and external ones to be used outside of a workflow (for example from a web server). 
You are trying to use an external client inside a workflow which is not supported. Use the internal client (created using ParentWorkflowClientFactory) instead. See [Flow Development Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/clients.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue. I missed the difference between the external and internal client.

Comment: BTW. The next version of the Flow framework doesn't even use generated code: https://github.com/uber-java/cadence-client